# Difference between unsigned long and DWORD?

Tags: c++

I am watching a tutorial in which someone is finding a process ID for a running program in C++ using the windows and TlHelp32 headers. He uses DWORDs which are a part of windows. According to documentation DWORDs are 32 bit unsigned integers. So, is there any difference between a DWORD and a unsigned int or unsigned long? If he replaced every instance of DWORD with unsigned long would it make any difference? If there are differences are they compile time or runtime differences? Thx.

Comment: Windows likes to make up its own terminology for everything on the planet. If you're invoking WinAPI calls, use DWORD and the Windows names. For everything else, use standard C++ names. It's a pain, but it's best to just be consistent in both cases. The actual machine sizes of `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are not specified in general (only minimum sizes are)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's because when Windows was written there wasn't anything like `uint32_t` or `int8_t` so defining your own type is the only way to make fixed-width types. Lots of GNU and Linux libraries do that same "silly" thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), `DWORD` is just an *alias* for `unsigned long`:

`typedef unsigned long DWORD;`

So no, there is no difference whatsoever between `DWORD` and `unsigned long`, they are the *exact* same thing.

There is, however, a difference between an `unsigned int` and an `unsigned long`. They are separate and distinct types, even though they have the same characteristics.